# Django ... Sum up a calculation from a database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

The postgres table has an entry for each job executed on one of the compute clusters. Included in the table are fields for the job epoch starting time (`g_start_time`), the job epoch ending time, the number of cores / processors used (`g_processors`), and the userid executing the job (`g_user_id`).

To calculate the cpu-years for a particular user, the math is `sum((g_end_time - g_start_time) * g_processors /60*60*2 4*365.25)`. Is there an appropriate "aggregate" method in Django to do this calculation, or do I need to iterate over a raw query to do the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to represent this exclusively with default QuerySet methods. But you can use the extra option:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Something like this:

```python
Entry.objects.extra(select={'cpu_years': "sum((g_end_time - g_start_time) * g_processors /60*60*2 4*365.25)"})
```

Comment: Extra looked like a solution. It's important that the calculation be made on each qualifying row and then summed rather than summing up each of the elements and then performing the calculation on the result (i.e., sum(a) * sum(b) != sum(a*b)). I'll try this to see if works correctly. Thanks for your response!